# Get GD image from multiple input text

Tags: jquery, forms, gd

I've currently got a GD image which gets it's input from a form which I wish to send without refreshing the page.

I've currently got 1 error, but I can't figure it out.

I haven't worked with jQuery before, but I've looked at all the .val docs and tried to find help other places, and that has not been successful.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {         
        $('#imgText').html('&lt;img src="imagecreator.php?param=' + $('input[name=username1]').val() + '"&param="'+ $('input[name=username2]').val() +    '" /&gt;');
    });
});​
```

[And here's a jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/954zK/14/)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to escape the html tags, and be careful with the quotes.

Try:

```
$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {         
        $('#imgText').html('<img src="imagecreator.php?param=' + $('input[name=username1]').val() + '&param='+ $('input[name=username2]').val() +    '" />');
    });
});​
```

And note: You have two parameters all with name `param`, the last one will overwrite the first one.

Comment: One more question. Since it takes quite some time for the external GD image to load, how can I add a loading gif while the process is grabbing the external image?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {         
        $('#imgText').html('&lt;img src="imagecreator.php?param=' + $('input[name=username1]').val() + '&amp;param='+ $('input[name=username2]').val() +    '" /&gt;');
    });
});​
```

Comment: One more question. Since it takes quite some time for the external GD image to load, how can I add a loading gif while the process is grabbing the external image?

Comment: Set the background style as the loading GIF and force it to have a specific size.  When the image loads it will cover the background.